# Making NSString global to whole project iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my iPhone application, on login to web services I get a session ID which gets changed on every login. I want to use that session ID for y other view controllers so that I would not have to use username password again and again and also I have to the session ID with the other links of web services to get the required JSON data to iPhone.

Should I define it as a macro or there is another way to do this.

```
session:"7e5085390e1877fd83f7346093c8304b"
```

If it can be done with macro then how can i achieve this?

On login url used as:

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url/rest/mobile/session"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[urlRequest addValue:user forHTTPHeaderField:@"uid" ];
[urlRequest addValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"passwd" ];
```

When getting data for other views:

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url/rest/assetgroups/7e5085390e1877fd83f7346093c8304b"];
```

Please let me have your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### As a Global Variable

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, one approach is to simply make a global variable, just like you would in C.  You want to declare the variable in a header file, like this:

#### Globals.h

```
extern NSString *sessionId;
```

Any .m file that needs to use `sessionId` can `#import "Globals.h"` to get the declaration.

You also need to define the variable in one of your .m files.  For example, you could add this to `main.m`, outside of any function definition:

#### main.m

```
NSString *sessionId;
```

### As an Application Delegate Property

Another approach is to make the variable be a property of your application delegate, since that is a globally-accessible object already.  You need to declare it in `AppDelegate.h`:

#### AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sessionId;

// other properties and methods of AppDelegate here

@end
```

and you synthesize it in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    // ivars here
}

@synthesize sessionId = _sessionId;

// Rest of AppDelegate method definitions and synthesizers here

@end
```

and you can access the property like this:

```
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = whatever();
NSLog(@"session id = %@", ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this 
        set the session

```
      NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [userDefault setObject:@"7e5085390e1877fd83f7346093c8304b" forKey:@"session"];
```

and get like this

```
   NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@",[userDefault objectForKey:@"session"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Making Global the `NSString`, you should declared this `NSString` in `AppDelegate  Class`

// declared `NSString` in `Delegate` Class

suppose you have `TestAppDelegate` class

// Now you can Access that String Object As below

```
TestAppDelegate* appDelegate=(TestAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication     sharedApplication]delegate];
```

//now you can access that string in any class throughout the App

```
appDelegate.stringObject;
```

Comment: I have defined NSMutableString *sessionID; in application delegate, now how can i access it in other view controllers

Comment: You Firstly import App delegate Class in ViewController Class then you should create instance of that delegate class as below   TestAppDelegate* appDelegate=(TestAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

//You can Access That String throughout the App
 here you can access that string in your Controller   class                                                                    appDelegate.sessionID;

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to use it as Login item, you can not add it as macro. I guess `NSUserDefault` will be a good option .