# Ios - how do I show/hide fields when a switch changes on/off

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a switch in my screen, and when the user wants that option to be on, I need to collect some more information from that user. So I need to present two text fields. And if the user does not want to use that feature, then they select the off switch, and I do not need to collect the contact information, and I would like to hide the text fields which collect the information.

Here is my sceen:

[image]

Where do I need to put the "listener" and the code to hide/show the extra text fields and labels when the user toggles a switch?

Thanks!

Comment: why not try to put these info in to UserDefault?

Comment: @lu yuan I am not too familiar with UserDefault - how can it be used in my case? Thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698178/making-nsstring-global-to-whole-project-iphone for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIViewController` containing the switch is the logical place to handle events coming from the switch.  From the image I see you already have the switch wired up.  You can declare an IBAction method and wire the switch's valueChanged event to it:

```
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged:(id)sender;
```

In the implementation of that method you can hide/show the labels and text fields.  The quick-and-dirty approach would be to have those extra labels and fields always present on the view, but hidden.  You can toggle the `hidden` property in response to the user toggling a switch.

You could also wrap those extra labels and fields inside a view which you dynamically add to or remove from the main view in response to a switch being toggled.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Value changed` of your UISwitch in the IB to detect changes from `OFF` to `ON` and vice versa (And link to your own `IBAction` methods!). Then you can hide the `UITextField` by just using this setter: `[textField setHidden:YES];`. Hope this is useful for you.